# Spring Data Neo4j OGM version and transaction isolation/propagation

Tags: spring, neo4j, transactions, spring-data-neo4j

I have a service method `mergeAndUpdateAndCompliance()` which uses Spring Data Neo4j OGM version:

```
@Transactional("neo4jTransactionManager")
@Override
public ComplianceMatrix mergeAndUpdateAndCompliance() {

        mergeAndUpdate();

        return compliance()
}


@Override
public void mergeAndUpdate() {
  //do some update operations
}

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true, transactionManager = "neo4jTransactionManager")
public void compliance() {
  //do some read operations
}
```

`mergeAndUpdateAndCompliance()` invokes two other service methods - `mergeAndUpdate()` and compliance(). compliance() reads the data updated by mergeAndUpdate(). Right now compliance() doesn't see the data updated in mergeAndUpdate() in the same transaction.

It works only if I add `session.getTransaction().commit();` between them:

```
@Autowired
private Session session;

@Transactional("neo4jTransactionManager")
@Override
public ComplianceMatrix mergeAndUpdateAndCompliance() {

        mergeAndUpdate();

        session.getTransaction().commit();

        return compliance()
}
```

Is it safe to place session.getTransaction().commit(); inside of Spring transaction ? What is the right way to solve this issue? Is it possible to use transaction propagation with SDN in order to configure `mergeAndUpdate` with REQUIRES_NEW ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have applied `@Transactional` on the `mergeAndUpdateAndCompliance`, function, within it is also applied to `compliance` method. You should try this way:

```
@Override
public ComplianceMatrix mergeAndUpdateAndCompliance() {
        mergeAndUpdate();
        return compliance()
}


@Override
@Transactional("neo4jTransactionManager")
public void mergeAndUpdate() {
  //do some update operations
}

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true, transactionManager = "neo4jTransactionManager")
public void compliance() {
  //do some read operations
}
```

Instead of applying it on the `mergeAndUpdateAndCompliance`, you should apply it on `mergeAndUpdate` and `compliance` functions separately. So that you don't have to manually commit the transaction.